# Opencart custom category sort by

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, opencart

Hi I have an issue when want to add a "Sort By" in category page based on product sold quantity.

I have got till here by adding the new sort query in model/catelog/product.php

```
if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
} elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";

//custom
} elseif ($data['sort'] == 'total_sold') { 

    $sql .= " ORDER BY (  ( SELECT sum( quantity ) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op where op.product_id=p.product_id GROUP BY p.product_id )) ";
```

Question is, how we can alter this quantity sold order by add in the quantity of the product field "jan". As now we have our own quantity sold adjustment in product "jan" field. So we need the Sort by
 (*real product sold as above statement*) + (value in jan field for each product).

Comment: Someone please help, appreciate so much.

Comment: Appreciate anyone please..